# How to compile Boost 1.61 for Android NDK 11

Tags: android, c++, boost

I want to install compile Boost 1.61 with clang 3.6 for android with the NDK 11 but this software : https://github.com/moritz-wundke/Boost-for-Android isn't updated and doesn't support this versions.

I want to know if anyone has managed to this !

Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

**Build boost_1_62_0 for Android-21 under Windows64.**

Assuming NDK installed to `C:\Programs\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle` and boost in `c:\boost_1_62_0`.

Install mingw: [using msys2-x86_64 from MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/)

Install build tools from mingw prompt (something like this):

```
$ pacman -S gcc binutils
```

Create android.clang.jam file in `C:\boost_1_62_0\` with such text content:

```
import os ;
local AndroidNDKRoot = C:/Programs/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle ;
using clang : android
:
C:/Programs/Android/toolchain21/bin/clang++
:
<compileflags>-fexceptions
<compileflags>-frtti
<compileflags>-fpic
<compileflags>-ffunction-sections
<compileflags>-funwind-tables
<compileflags>-Wno-psabi
<compileflags>-march=armv7-a
<compileflags>-mfloat-abi=softfp
<compileflags>-mfpu=vfpv3-d16
<compileflags>-fomit-frame-pointer
<compileflags>-fno-strict-aliasing
<compileflags>-finline-limit=64
<compileflags>-I$(AndroidNDKRoot)/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include
<compileflags>-Wa,--noexecstack
<compileflags>-DANDROID
<compileflags>-D__ANDROID__
<compileflags>-DNDEBUG
<compileflags>-O2
#<compileflags>-g
<compileflags>-I$(AndroidNDKRoot)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include
<compileflags>-I$(AndroidNDKRoot)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include
<architecture>arm
<compileflags>-fvisibility=hidden
<compileflags>-fvisibility-inlines-hidden
<compileflags>-fdata-sections
<cxxflags>-D__arm__
<cxxflags>-D_REENTRANT
<cxxflags>-D_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS
;
```

Setup boost from mingw prompt:

```
$ export NDK=/c/Programs/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
$ echo ensure msi-installed Python is on path (not msys version):
$ export PATH=/c/Python27:$PATH
$ $NDK/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch arm --api 21 --install-dir /c/Programs/Android/toolchain21
$ ./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc
$ ./b2 --user-config=android.clang.jam threading=multi link=static \
runtime-link=static toolset=clang-android target-os=linux \
threadapi=pthread --stagedir=android --with-chrono \
--with-program_options --with-system --with-thread --with-random \
--with-regex
```

Comment: I just need the boost 1.62.0, could you please share the built files ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the repository you mentioned is apparently not maintained anymore. The author also seems not to answer any mails on the subject. If you look you'll see that each new boost version supported there required a lot of work (many special flags in the config files). That's presumably why he doesn't have time to maintain it any longer.
I also tried to update to 1.64 using a fork but gave up after countless error messages and instead  used a different method based on a crystax script. Its simple and should work for pretty much any version.  You can find the details and the script (simple and painless to execute) here: http://silverglint.com/boost-for-android/ 
Works with clang and gcc.

Also included is a sample app that shows you how to use the boost binaries thus built.